# Nginx + PHP-FPM = 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I just spun up a new Rackspace cloud server and ran the following:

```
apt-get install php5 nginx php-fpm
```

When I navigate to the IP address, I see the default Nginx message. I then copied my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file from another working setup I have:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root /srv/www;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /controllers$uri.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
      }
   }
}
```

I created `index.php` in `/srv/www` and started `nginx` and `php-fpm`:

```
/etc/init.d/nginx start
/etc/init.d/php5-fpm start
```

I'm getting a 502 Bad Gateway error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I can't add comment, I'll post it as an answer...

Check `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (or the file in there) if it's set to run on TCP or UNIX socket. Also check if the PHP is actually running. And look into the log files `/var/log/php5-fpm.log` or `/var/log/php5-fpm/*` and `/var/log/nginx/*` (depends on settings).

You should find the cause of the error there.

Comment: I opened `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and found `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`. I changed it to `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and everything is working now. I totally forgot about that one-line configuration! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

In my case the solutions was:

1- To Change the lister like @David:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

On the file search `listen =`, comment ...sock and add 127.0.0.1:9000

```
;listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

2- Change on Nginx Site conf (Ex. /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com)

```
server {
       .
       .
       . 
location ~ \.php$ {
       .
       .
       .
 #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
       .
       .
       .
```

3- Increment the timeout and max_children:

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini  =>   default_socket_timeout = 60000
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini  =>   pm.max_children = 20
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf  =>   request_terminate_timeout = 60000
```

4- Incremente timeout on /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
keepalive_timeout 65000;
```

After Restart php-fpm and nginx:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

I recommend before restart nginx to test if all is OK:

```
sudo service nginx configtest
```

Answer (score 1):

The bad gateway error means that the php process is responding with an error. Can you check your php error log? Also try placing a file test.php with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` @ /srv/www/ and then try to hit that domain directly from the command line of your server ala:

`curl http://127.0.0.1:9000/test.php;`

Have you checked the obvious things like you have a file @ /srv/www/index.php? Have you run ps aux and grepped for nginx and php to make sure they are running?

How about running: `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` to make sure the php-fpm daemon is listening?

Comment: I ran `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` and saw that nothing was listening on 127.0.0.1:9000. I opened `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` and found `listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock`. I changed it to `listen = 127.0.0.1:9000` and everything is working now. I thought this was the default setting and I forgot to check it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case `restart` for fpm service worked. I only ran `reload`. Forgot that conf changes needs restart to apply.